# Tensorflow keras model_load error: ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I built a model that consists of a pre-learnt model followed by some layers that are added to the end. Everything works well and I can train the model on my dataset and save the trained model to file. But when I try to load the saved model, I get the following error. I get that this points to the Dense layer shape being undefined. However I specified the input shape to the model before training and made sure that the resulting Dense layer will have a predetermined shape. Not sure how to address the issue

This is the model that was designed

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input((320, 640, 3)))

    vgg_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

    model.add(vgg_model)

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('linear'))
    
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001)
    model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = optimizer)
  
    return model


model = create_model()
model.fit(data_generator, epochs = 1)
model.save(model_folder + '/model.h5')
```

After training the model on my dataset I am trying to load into in an other script

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_folder + '/model.h5')
```

This leads to the following error

```
raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

I am using tensorflow version 2.1.0 and keras version 2.3.1

Any idea, why this is happening and how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: It is advised not to mix ```keras``` and ```tensorflow.keras``` imports. All keras imports should be ```from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense```. Maybe try that?

Comment: I made a change to not save the model as '.h5' file and allow tensorflow to save it in its won way by just specifying a directory path. And it worked when I did that. The new save command will be  `model.save(model_folder + '/model')`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify the input_shape as per [tf docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/VGG16) where it states

> input_shape:  optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top is False (otherwise the input shape has to be (224,
> 224, 3)

In your case `vgg_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=((320, 640, 3)))` may help?